# objectdb : update child set<> of the parent after remove one child doesn't work

Tags: jpa, objectdb

In my application I have two entity Person and Activity

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
  .
  .
  .
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval=true)
  Set<Activity> a;

  // getters setters constructors
}
```

... and...

```
@Entity
public class Activity
{
  .
  .
  .
  // getters setters constructors
}
```

1. In the first place I create two Activity's objects
2. I add activity's objects to a Person object
3. I persist the Person object (the two activity objects are persisted, it work fine)
4. Then I delete one Activity object from my database
5. I select my Person object from the database

The result is a Person object with `Set<Activity>` with `size=2`.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the Activity object from the database you have to update the set in Person and remove that Activity object also from the set. Otherwise you will have a broken reference to a non existing Activity object in the set.

On the other hand, since you enabled [orphanRemoval](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Orphan_Removal_), you can just remove the Activity from the set in Person and it should be removed automatically also from the database.

Another option is to define the set as [mappedBy](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/fields#Inverse_Fields_) and then the set will be updated automatically when an Activity is removed from the database, when the Person object is loaded again from the database or refreshed.

Comment: but how to add mappedBy wit my unidirectional association. because the set<Person> in the Activity class I don't need it.

Comment: You will have to add a reference from Activity to Person.